# Why do I see a tiny number in the corner of VMware Workstation?

Tags: vmware-workstation

In the corner of VMware Workstation, I see a tiny, inexplicable, unclickable, un-Googlable number. It appears on top of everything. I think it used to be a 1, now it's a 2.

**What's up with this number?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows?  I assume if you create a new virtual machine this number is not present?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise inside VM and host. You're right, in a different VM, I don't see the number.